# Excel to XML xsd:date schema format, "what if" statement for xsd?

Tags: xml, excel, date, xsd

I am using Excel to convert my data to an XML. One of the fields is a date. My problem is that the dates are not a consistent format: YYYY or YYYY-MM-DD or even sometimes a string value of text and date (e.g. "circa 1920s).

I need a solution for the schema recognizing that the field contains either a date value or a string value.

My schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element nillable="true" name="metadata">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" name="record" form="unqualified">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:date" name="date" form="unqualified"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Dates example:

```
Date
1921-06-01
1919
1921-06-01
1921
```

I've gone back and forth using 'xsd:date' and 'xsd:string', but the formatting of Excel does not translate over. When mapping the schema to the field, the date field prompts the user to choose either the current formatting or to match the element formatting. Either way, the YYYY and YYYY-MM-DD do not both show up, one is always changed. I'd like to have both. Thoughts?

Thanks.